# Recurtion equation

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory

Does anyone know how to solve the below? 
I'm guessing that I need to use the Subtraction method or iteration but still I'm having a hard time with it.

$$T(n)=3T(n-1)+3^n\times n^2$$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Solving or approximating recurrence relations for sequences of numbers](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/2789/solving-or-approximating-recurrence-relations-for-sequences-of-numbers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exapnd the equation:

$$T(n) = 3(3T(n-2) + 3^{n-1}\times(n-1)^2) + 3^n\times n^2=$$
$$3^2T(n-2) + 3^n(n^2 + (n-1)^2)= \cdots = $$
$$3^n\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2 = 3^n \times \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} = \Theta(3^n\times n^3) $$

Comment: i don't understand the second and the third lines. can you explain it in more details ?

Comment: @OmerMichleviz I have just expanded the equation recursively.

Comment: i dont understand the ". . ." .the sigma...how did you notice it? whats going on there

Comment: @OmerMichleviz Replace $T(n-2)$ and follow the pattern in the equation.